# Wget from Bash translate to Python with flags

Tags: python, bash, wget

I have the following bash wget command

> wget -rHncp --cut-dirs=1 -A .txt -e robots=off -l1 -i ./ids.txt -B 'http://archive.org/download/'

I would like to be able to run the exact same command in Python. However, this python file will have to be compatible to running on a windows machine without bash or the wget command. Would I be able to use the wget python package for this? I've tried, but I haven't figured out how to pass it flags yet.

Edit: March 31, 2017

The purpose of the command is to download multiple files from archive.org's website. Given a filetype (in this instance a `.txt`) and given a file with a list of identifiers (in this instance, the file is call `ids.txt`), this command will download every txt file associated with the given identifiers.

One such identifier is `aeneid_391` and the resulting file from this identifier is `virgiletext95anide10_djvu.txt`.

Comment: in python you can use `curl` lib. but it lacks web-spider functionality (so no recursive downloads etc), this part you have to do on your own.

Comment: If you could add a description of exactly what your BASH command is doing, so we do not have to go into wget's manual to figure it all out.. it would be a lot easier to create some useful answer for your question. Right now, people answering this either need to be fully knowledgeable of all wget's functions or they have to be willing to invest the time to read its manual

Comment: To be completely honest with you @SB87, I don't know what's going on either. I got this command from archive.org's website. But I'll explain what is going on better

Comment: It's always better to understand your own code. You could execute `man wget` in a terminal and find out what `wget -r`, `wget -H`, `wget -n`, etc. stand for since they are all being applied here. Beware though, executing this code in python is probably easy to accomplish but would likely require installing some additional modules, will you be able to do so on the mentioned computer? Since simply installing wget would seem more straight forward..? What shell is that computer running on if not Bash?

Comment: For instance running your code in Python could easily be done via a subprocess.Popen().. but that would not be the most Pythonic way though.. and still require wget to be installed. If using other modules, you should really be able to explain in more detail what your wget script is doing. It is doing more then just reading lines from a file and downloading them.